# Docker multi container networking on same host

Tags: networking, docker

So, I have database container and a webserver container running on the same OSX machine.

If, I use below to start webserver container:

```
 docker run --name ora-tools-wls -it -p 7001:7001 orawls
```

accessing webserver in host browser as   `http://localhost:7001/console` works just fine. The problem is: the database connection would require the host machine ip to access the DB running into DB container.

Now, I use instead:

```
docker run --name ora-tools-wls -it --net="host" orawls
```

accessing db from webserver works fine with localhost and without specific ip. However, accessing console in host browser then stops working.

I need both to be working. So what is the solution

Comment: What you are looking for is [`docker networking`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make a non-hardcoded URL path in docker image to call backend service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216713/how-to-make-a-non-hardcoded-url-path-in-docker-image-to-call-backend-service)

Comment: run it in docker-compose syntax version 2 and you will have automatic network and services discovery and you will be able to reference your services (containers) but their name.